# Query inside custom validator

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, validation

I have written class-level JSR-303 constraint annotation that accepts a method name as a parameter. The method name that you set as parameter should return a boolean value.

I have entity Foo with fields code, validFrom and validTill. The code must be unique in every time.
Example: 
two entities ('AAA',1.1.2010,31.12.2010) and ('AAA',1.5.2011,31.5.2011) are OK
two entities ('AAA',1.1.2010,31.12.2010) and ('AAA',1.2.2010,31.3.2012) are WRONG

Now I need to write validation method which check if code is unique.
I wrote:

```
    public boolean isUnique() {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Before select");
    return entityManager.createQuery("select count(o) from Currency o where " +
            "o.code = :code and (" +
            "(o.validFrom between :validFrom and :validTill) or " +
            "(o.validTill between :validFrom and :validTill) or " +
            "(:validFrom between o.validFrom and o.validTill))",
            Long.class)
            .setParameter("code", getCode())
            .setParameter("validFrom", getValidFrom())
            .setParameter("validTill", getValidTill())
            .getSingleResult() == 0;
}
```

I got into quite infinite loop

```
DEBUG http-8080-2 ch.laic.bsatrak.domain.base.BaseEntity - Before select
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - processing flush-time cascades
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - dirty checking collections
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.pretty.Printer - listing entities:
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.pretty.Printer - ch.laic.bsatrak.domain.base.Currency{id=50, createdBy=, editedBy=, createdAt=2011-04-07T14:54:52.233+02:00, validFrom=2010-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00, code=CODE, validTill=2010-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00, suspended=false, version=0, editedAt=null}
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue - changes must be flushed to space: bs_currency
DEBUG http-8080-2 ch.laic.bsatrak.domain.base.BaseEntity - Before select
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - processing flush-time cascades
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - dirty checking collections
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.pretty.Printer - listing entities:
DEBUG http-8080-2 org.hibernate.pretty.Printer - ch.laic.bsatrak.domain.base.Currency{id=50, createdBy=, editedBy=, createdAt=2011-04-07T14:54:52.233+02:00, validFrom=2010-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00, code=CODE, validTill=2010-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00, suspended=false, version=0, editedAt=null}
```

How can I do this correct way?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to set FlushMode. Default is Auto and before query framework try to flush all entities which can have influence on query.

```
.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT)
```